# set images in horizontal view in a custom camera layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

PS: This is an update of previously asked question.

I have a custom camera layout where I need the images to be set in a horizontal  as and when they are clicked. I tried using recyclerview for this. 
First, The image is clicked is stored in a bitmap called *result*.

Then, I store the path of the image in a variable called *path*. The path variable is passed to the RecycleViewAdapter through bundle.

And then, using the onBindViewHolder, I'm trying to display the image in a horizontal view.

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            camera.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {
                    super.onPictureTaken(picture);
                         Bitmap result = 
   BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);

                         ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                         result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, bytes);

                         String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), result, "Title", null);
                    horizontalList.add(path);
                         recycleViewAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(horizontalList);
                         horizontal_rv.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);
                         recycleViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mBundle = new Bundle();
                    CameraActivity.mBundle.putString("abc", path);
                    horizontalList.add(path);
                }
            });
            camera.captureImage();

        }
    });
```

And then passed to the adapter class.

```
    public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Uri uri;
String path;
private List<Bitmap> horizontalList;
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image_result;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        image_result = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_result);

    }
}

public RecycleViewAdapter(ArrayList<Bitmap> horizontalList) {
    this.horizontalList = horizontalList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
     path= CameraActivity.mBundle.getString("abc");
    uri=Uri.parse(path);
    holder.image_result.setImageURI(uri);


    holder.image_result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return horizontalList.size();
}
}
```

**Problem:**
When I click an image, at each click 2 copies are shown in the image. And the previous views are changed showing the new image, doubling the count. 
Also, the app crashes after max 3 clicks.

A screenshot is:
[image]

Please help.

Comment: As a word of caution, keeping a list of bitmap objects in your adapter may give you an OutOfMemoryException quickly, try keeping string references or Uris rather. I will also recommend you use Picasso or Glide to do the loading as it is easier to use.

Comment: you are always creating new instance of adapter hence it takes only sibgle value(newest one)

Comment: Yes, I got that error. I was thinking to get this done, and then move to that issue. Thanks though.

Comment: @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt please elaborate. I am not getting even a single image display.

Comment: you are passing list in your adapter but you are not using that list anywhere in adapter, get value of your path from that list only

Comment: make a model type list and pass it to the adapter and in bindview holder get value from that list

Comment: Did you forget to set the adapter? I also recommend you use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged instead of manually recreating the adapter always

Comment: @CoolGuyCG I have the adapter set. Its in onCreate function. I didn't share the code.

Comment: @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt i tried  Bitmap bmp=horizontalList.get(0);
        holder.image_result.setImageBitmap(bmp); Not sure if this makes sense. But this didn't display anything either.

Comment: You can store path to arraylist instead of bitmap to adapter class and load images in adapter using _Glide_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//I assume you are looping here
Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), result, "Title", null);

                    CameraActivity.mBundle.putString("abc",path);
                    horizontalList.add(result);
                   // finish loop....................
//notify the adapter of data changes
recycleViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Creating a new adapter inside the loop means only a single item can be displayed while also being inefficient. Loop and add the elements in the loop and after the loop, notify the adapter of data changes.

Comment: This might be very lame, but the .notifyDatasetChanged is giving error. Cannot resolve method

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is the correct method. You should enable typing suggestions/intellisense in your ide in case it is not enabled